# WPF: Check/Uncheck all checkbox for checkboxes located in gridview cell template?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, gridview, checkbox

I'm trying to create a check/uncheck all `CheckBox` for a number of `CheckBoxes` that are located inside the cell template of a `GridViewColumn`. I added this column to a `GridView` (along with other columns), set the `GridView` to the view property of a `ListView`, and then databound the `ListView` to a collection of custom `DataObjects`. So, each row of the `ListView` has a column that contains a checkbox as well as columns bound to property paths of the bound object.

I would like to create the check/uncheck all `CheckBox` by binding the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBoxes`, but I do not want to change the data object the `ListView` is bound to. My first attempt was to bind the ListView to a `Dictionary<DataObject,Boolean>` and then bind the `IsChecked` property to the `Value` of the `Dictionary` and the other columns to `Key`.*`DataObjectProperty`*. Then, I simply toggled the `Values` of the Dictionary when then check/uncheck all `CheckBox` was clicked. The binding to worked properly, but apparently dictionaries don't support change notification so the `CheckBoxes` were never updated.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think is to wrap your DataObject and boolean inside a new class which implements INotofyPropertyChanged. say the new class is YourCollection. Bind an `ObservableCollection< YourNewClass  >` instance to your ListView

```
   public class YourNewClass :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public YourDataObject Object { get; set; }

    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return _isChecked;
        }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent idea, thank you. This would still work if YourNewClass was generic where the generic argument is the type of YourDataObject correct? That is: 
public class YourNewClass <T> :INotifyPropertyChanged 
{ 
public T Object { get; set; } 
... 
}