# Multicheck DataGridCheckBoxColumns

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am new to WPF and stuck on this problem:

I want to enable a multi -check/uncheck of my DataGridComboBoxColumns for the selected Rows in the "clicked" column.

My DataGrid looks like

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedListRTEntity.Properties}"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      CanUserAddRows="False"
      CanUserDeleteRows="False"
      >
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Visibility="Hidden" Binding="{Binding ID}" />
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Generate" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Generate}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Is nullable" Width="100" Binding="{Binding IsNullable}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Basic type" Width="100" Binding="{Binding BasicType}" />
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="UseCustomGetterSetter" Width="100" Binding="{Binding UseCustomGetterSetter}" /> 
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Its realy important, that the multicheck checks the checkboxes in the right column.

I have no idea how to handle this issue.
Is there a way to solve this without codebehind ?

**EDIT:** Maybe this Screenshot will help to clarify, what I mean:

First select the rows which i want to uncheck with SHIFT + click
[image]

Then uncheck them with SHIFT + Click in one of the checkboxes

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by multicheck ? Are you trying to say that Column header has a checkbox, and checking it will check all checkboxes in that column. Please clarify.

Comment: No I dont need a checkbox in the column header.
I want to make it possible to check / uncheck multi lines with Shift + click.
I add some screenshots to my post to clarify what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without writing code it is not possible to achieve desired effect. You need to have property bound to Checkbox to be notifiable. So, implement INotifyPropertyChanged for those properties.

After doing below changes, when I check/uncheck any Generate checkbox in any selected row, all checkboxes for Generate field does same for selected rows. Unselected rows remain un-effected.

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="myGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedListRTEntity.Properties}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        CanUserDeleteRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Visibility="Hidden" Binding="{Binding ID}" />

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="100" Header="Generate">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding Generate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                   Checked="GenerateCheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="GenerateCheckBox_Unchecked"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Is nullable" Width="100" Binding="{Binding IsNullable}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Basic type" Width="100" Binding="{Binding BasicType}" />
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="UseCustomGetterSetter" Width="100" Binding="{Binding UseCustomGetterSetter}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Your Property class :

```
    public class Property:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       public String ID { get; set; }

       public String Name { get; set; }
       public bool IsNullable { get; set; }
       public String BasicType { get; set; }
       public bool UseCustomGetterSetter { get; set; }

       private bool _generate;
       public bool Generate { 
           get { return _generate; } 
           set { _generate = value; OnPropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Generate"));  } 
       }

       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
       void OnPropertyChanged(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
               PropertyChanged(this, e);
       }
    }
```

In code-behind

```
        private void GenerateCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            IList items = myGrid.SelectedItems;

            foreach (Property p in items) 
            {
                p.Generate = true; 
            } 
        } 

        private void GenerateCheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            IList items = myGrid.SelectedItems;

            foreach (Property p in items)
            {
                p.Generate = false;
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement this you can add a check box in your column header and then bind its command to a viewmodel command.

that command handler will set all item's property to whatever you want.

Read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969340/wpf-gridview-with-multiple-checkbox-columns-and-select-all-column-header) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326374/wpf-check-uncheck-all-checkbox-for-checkboxes-located-in-gridview-cell-template) to get better idea.